# Looping through a specific column and then assigning a value to a button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on a school assignment where I import data into a `DataGridView` in `WinForm` from a `CSV` file. This all works perfect, however, now I want to assign a value to a button (In column 5, 6 and 8) These can all vary depending on what the value in the same row, in column 3 is. If the value from column 3 is "Input" on the same row, in column 5, the button needs to be "Input", the rest of the cells in that row after column 5 need to be readonly textboxes.

If the value from column 3 is "Output" on the same row, in column 5, the button needs to be "On", in column 6 it needs to be "Off" and in column 8 it needs to be "On #s"

I've tried:

Looping through all the cells, foreach loops, looping through column 3, but I'm not sure how I can change the value of button in the same row. (They also need to have a different function when you click them, but I think that is easier when I understand how this works)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ofNI.png) is a preview of the CSV file that needs to be used.

This is the code I've written so far (thats working):

```cs
private void btnBevestig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LaadCSVToDataGrid(openFile.FileName);
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[3], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btnInput = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnInput);
        btnInput.HeaderText = "Functie";
        btnInput.Text = "Input";
        btnInput.Name = "colInput";
        btnInput.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btnOff = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnOff);
        btnOff.HeaderText = "";
        btnOff.Text = "Off";
        btnOff.Name = "colInput";
        btnOff.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtAantalSeconden = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(txtAantalSeconden);
        txtAantalSeconden.HeaderText = "";
        txtAantalSeconden.Name = "txtAantalSec";
        txtAantalSeconden.ReadOnly = false;

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btnOnSec = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnOnSec);
        btnOnSec.HeaderText = "";
        btnOnSec.Text = "Aantal seconden";
        btnOnSec.Name = "colInput";
        btnOnSec.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

        btnOntgrendel.Enabled = true;
        comboBoxProfiel.Enabled = false;
        btnBevestig.Enabled = false;
        btnKiesProfiel.Enabled = false;
        btnNieuwProfiel.Enabled = false;

    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            error.Message,
            "Fout",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning
            );
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ColumnIndex);
    Console.WriteLine(e.RowIndex);
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToString() == "Input")
        {
            dataGridView1[5, e.RowIndex].Value = "Input";
            Console.WriteLine(e.ColumnIndex);
            Console.WriteLine(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Handle the [DataGridView.CellValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=net-5.0) event, check if `e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex >= 0`, get the current cell value like `if (dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToString() == "something")`, and set the cells (5, 6, and 8) values/properties of the same row accordingly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "Set the cells (5, 6 and 8) values = properties of the same row accordingly" What I mean is that column 5, 6 and 8 are changed accordingly.

Comment: I didn't say that `values = properties` ! I said, get the current value of  the cell in question and do whatever you want according to that value.

Comment: Woopsies my bad, my = and / are right next to eachother. I'm guessing that getting the value would be `if (dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ToString() == "something")` ? How exactly would I navigate through that row to column 5, 6 and 8?

Comment: `dgv[5, e.RowIndex].Value = "..."`, and the same for columns 6 and 8. The same for the other properties of the cells..

Comment: So I've done those both (see bottom of the code) but I wont change the value, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This was changed however the button in column 5 still does not change the text in the button.

Comment: Yes, you need to remove/comment `btnInput.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;`. It should be `false`.

Comment: @dr.null still nothing.  [This] [1] is my datagridview right now. <[1]: https://imgur.com/a/di0YHDp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the additional columns are added after populating the data, you need to loop over and set the values of the target cells according to the value of the **Input** cells.

```cs
private void UpdateCells()
{
    foreach (var r in dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow))
    {
        var v = r.Cells[3].Value?.ToString();

        if (v == "Input")
        {
            r.Cells[5].Value = "Input";
            // other changes ...
        }
        else
        {
            r.Cells[5].Value = "On";
            // Other changes ...
        }    
    }
}
```

Call this method after setting up the grid:

```cs
private void btnBevestig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LaadCSVToDataGrid(openFile.FileName);
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[3], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        btnInput.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = false;
        // ...

        UpdateCells()
    }
    catch { ... }
}
```

If the values of the read-only third column are changed at runtime by code, then handle the `CellValueChanged` event as well to update the target cells:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && !dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        var v = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value?.ToString();

        if (v == "Input")
        {
            dataGridView1[5, e.RowIndex].Value = "Input";
            // other changes ...
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1[5, e.RowIndex].Value = "On";
            // Other changes ...
        }
    }
}
```